# Authorization header not sent in Angular 2 JSONP request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cors, jsonp

I am making a JSONP call and is required to pass the bearer token in authorization header. However, despite the addition of headers to my code, an authorization header is not added to the request (check this in Fiddler). The code leverages Angular 2 and TypeScript. Here is my code -

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token  });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
    this.url = "http://api.azurewebsites.net/api/search/" + params;

    return this.jsonp.request(this.url, options)  
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
```

What am I missing here?.

Comment: I guess it should be `let headers = new Headers({'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token  }`

Comment: The code doesn't build if I used comma instead of a colon. Throws an exception mentioning, ";" expected. To be exact -  TS1005: ':' expected.

Comment: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token } is standard and should work. I think the error is because you're using `withCredentials` and not including a second parameters of credentials. Either remove `withCredentials` or change to `this.jsonp.request(this.url, '', options)`

Comment: try using `header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);` after declaring

Comment: @Aravind - I tried but the behavior is same, header is not passed

Comment: @NitinRastogi try removing the `withCredentials: true`

Comment: @Aravind. I thought the whole idea of withCredentials is to tell, it's coming with Authorization header. I removed it, but still didn't work

Comment: @Z.Bagley - I didn't see an overload you suggested with ''

Comment: @NitinRastogi are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: @Aravind Unfortunately not

Comment: If your jsonp request doesn't manage w/ credentials then leave it out. A standard http request will add the extra field when it's true. This is likely a CORS issue tbh.

Comment: @Z.Bagley My code is managing the token and in order to succeed, a token as part of the call is sent via jsonp and you are absolutely correct this is CORS, but I have necessary enablement done on the server side for accepting calls from origin and necessary headers.

Comment: And you're certain that a `CORS: *` header is being returned?

Comment: Meant `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` by that, fyi

Comment: As far as CORS goes, you don’t need CORS support for JSONP to work.  I don’t know what 'jsonp.request' but if it’s causing a script element to get added to the document, and so the request is loaded from a script element, then CORS is irrelevant

Comment: @Z.Bagley - Yep, I had the origin enabled for access as well as the additional headers are enabled as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using JSONP, then you can’t require authorization using an `Authorization` header. Instead, unless you configure some other means of authorization, the endpoint you’re returning the JSONP from must respond to requests from anywhere, with no `Authorization` header needed.

The reason you’re not able to add the `Authorization` header to the request is that if you’re using JSONP then you can’t add *any* request headers to the request. That’s because JSONP works by adding a `script` element to the document, and then setting the request URL as the value of the `src` attribute for that `script` element.

So you can’t add request headers to the request the browser makes to fetch the URL for that `script` element—no more than you can add request headers for any other `script` element.

If you want to require authorization using an `Authorization`-header, then you need to make the request using a normal method like XHR or the Fetch API or in Angular, a normal `$http.get(…)`.

And in that case, the API endpoint needs to be enabled with full CORS support, including support for the [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) the browser will automatically make on its own due to the presence of the `Authorization` request header in the request.

Comment: Thank You @sideshowbarker, great explanation around JSON's script elements and header part. That sets the clarity around how things work! I did change my code to use http.get and I do see Options Preflight happening, but I think there is an issue with my token as well. Will post back and accept the accept the answer, but a nice mention of basics!